# Why is $v=|u|^{\alpha}$ in $C^{1}_{c}(\mathbb{R}^n)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Why is $v=|u|^{\alpha}$ in $C^{1}_{c}(\mathbb{R}^n)$

for $u \in C^{1}_{c}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and ${\alpha}>1$?

Comment: $|x|$ on $\mathbb{R}$ is not differentiable at zero. Am I missing something? (I mean ok $x$ is not in $C_c^1(\mathbb{R})$ but you can change it outside $[-1,1]$ to be whatever you want)

Comment: ups, i forgot to write a>1

Comment: I believe you want to show that the derivative is $\alpha |u|^{\alpha-1}$.

Comment: Of course, because I study Gagliardo-Nirenberg-Sobolev inequality and don´t see why v is there.

Answer (score 1):

Define $g:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ by setting $g(t)=|t|^\alpha.$ Verify that $g'(t)=\alpha |t|^{\alpha -1}\text {sgn } t.$ Conclude that $g\in C^1(\mathbb R).$

Your function is $g\circ u.$ This is the composition of two $C^1$ functions, hence is $C^1.$ That it has compact support should be clear.

Comment: Sry, I forgot a>1

Comment: I've changed my answer to reflect the $\alpha >1$  assumption.